# Avoid the searchBar to expand after use

Tags: ios, uitableview, header, tableview, uisearchbar

I am making a function for a header view with 2 views on top of a tableView. I want to give each UIView half of the width of the tableview.  It works fine at the first loading, but after I first use the search bar, it expands automatically and it fills 100% of the tableview width.

```
func headerView() {

var textfieldView = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
tableView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
tableView.addSubview(textfieldView)

}

func searchbar() {

searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self as UISearchResultsUpdating
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rectangle"), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)

}
```

I would also appreciate help for setting a dynamic width as half of the tableview width (tableview.width / 2 ?) instead of a fixed one (200pixels)

Comment: it happens because search bar opens searchController and refresh frame of UISearchbar. Use UITextfield instead of searchcontroller if need to do changes in view of searchbar. And for half size of screen you can use UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 .

Comment: Try updating the frame of searchController searchBar in the following method, viewWillLayoutSubviews().

Comment: thanks, I could fix the size with UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, but I still have the same problem.  I tried with @Bharath function and it works while I am typing in the search bar ,but after pressing Cancel, then the searchBar expands itself and covers the uitextfield

Comment: Oh Good, One other suggestion, instead of setting the frame by code, I hope you could make use of autolayout(searchcontroller's width matching view's width using aspect ration of 1:2) would address the issue better.

Comment: I tried auto layout too, but I think that for some reason the searchBar just doesn't work when is not full width